# Paging the group member result

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, active-directory-group

[Microsoft graph API](https://graph.windows.net/Tenant.onmicrosoft.com/groups/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/members?$top=5&api-version=1.6) returns the correct result, but unable to perform the paging.

Is it possible with Microsoft Graph or Ad Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in the Microsoft Graph.  More info can be found in the documentation page for [Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging%20Paging%20Microsoft%20Graph%20data%20in%20your%20app).

When getting the list of members, there's a `@odata.nextLink` property that represents the next page of results.  For example, if you `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group-id]/members` the response looks like:

```
  { 
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group-id]/members?$skiptoken=X%2744537074070001000000000000000013233333100000000%27",
    "value": [...]    
  }
```

You can now make another GET request to the value of the next link.

Comment: It was my mistake, there was only 5 users in that result, that the reason I was not getting next link.